# How does webpack deal with images?

Tags: javascript, webpack

If it can't bundle images, where do the images go? Do you need another process aside from webpack to copy images to a certain directory (like Gulp)

Comment: `where do the images go?`, it depends on the config, you can have them embedded, or external.  If you have lots of large images, embedding them wouldn't really be the best option.

Comment: Suggested reading :) https://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Answer (score 2):

In your webpack config, you'll need to add a rule for file-loader, as such:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {test: /\.svg|\.png|\.jpg$/, use: ['file-loader']},
  ]
}
```

You can install file-loader from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)

Answer (score 0):

Images in many cases need to be imported. For example at the top of your app.js you can do

```
import '../../../css/bb_client_flow.png';
```

Then in your code include a tag referencing the image in your assets folder.

```
<img src="/assets/bb_client_flow.png" className="auth-flow"/>
```

This will put your images into the assets folder automatically. If you use a loader, and something like this in your webpack config.

```
{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|json|xml|ico|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'assets/',
              publicPath: '/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Finally I want to recommend the use of the picture tag and the use of different size images for [different screen sizes](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-responsive-images#6_optional_use_the_picture_and_source_elements) as this will improve you load time and UX depending on the device.

```
<figure>
    <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 750px)"
            srcset="images/horses-1600_large_2x.jpg 2x,
                    images/horses-800_large_1x.jpg" />
    <source media="(min-width: 500px)"
            srcset="images/horses_medium.jpg" />
    <img src="images/horses_small.jpg" alt="Horses in Hawaii">
    </picture>
    <figcaption>Horses in Hawaii</figcaption>
</figure>
```